# How to convert this tibble?

Tags: r

I am trying to convert a tibble with a single row to turn it into a table with 2 columns.
Here's my example :
Many thanks in advance !

```
library(tibble)

mydf <- tribble(
  ~colA, ~colB, ~colC, ~colD,
  "a",   "1",   "X",   "2"
)

# What I want
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  carac value
  <chr> <chr>
  colA  a    
  colB  1    
  colC  X    
  colD  2
```

Comment: `tidyr::pivot_longer()` should do the trick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `pivot_longer` from `tidyr` to reshape the whole dataset into 'long' format with two columns

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
mydf %>% 
   pivot_longer(cols = everything(), names_to = 'carac')
```

-ouptut

```
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  carac value
  <chr> <chr>
1 colA  a    
2 colB  1    
3 colC  X    
4 colD  2
```

---

In `base R`, we could use `stack` (if needed, set the column names differently)

```
stack(mydf)[2:1]
```